# splash screen in Intel App framework

Tags: android, mobile, appframework

how to implement the splash screen in mobile app using intel app framework?

I have tried this. This code display the image. But it is showing for long time. I wish to show it for little duration only. How to do this.? 
Advance Thanks for your answers.

Comment: can you post code on how you are doing

Answer (score 0):

try with handler in splash screen like this :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // make sure we close the splash screen so the user won't come back when it presses back key
                 finish();
                 if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {
                    // start the home screen if the back button wasn't pressed already 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Next_Activity.class); 
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
               }

            }

        }, Constant.SPLASH_DURATION); 

 @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

        // set the flag to true so the next activity won't start up
        mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
```

Comment: your answer has nothing to do with the Intel App Framework (JavaScript framework)

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen is displayed until

```
$af.ui.launch()
```

is run.

Search your code for this line

```
window.setTimeout(function () { $af.ui.launch(); }, 1500);
```

and change the 1500 to something smaller.